# Javascript readin txt file into chart

Tags: javascript, html, charts, txt

I really need some help to figure this out...

I have found a code which plot a chart out of values he gets from a website.
This is close what I would like to achieve.
But I dont want to get the values from the website but from a txt file.

I read that I should use json strings to convert it, but I'm not a programmer so I don't understand how to do such thing.

At the end of my question I have the code that get its value from the internet.

The txt file needs for now to be just easy like:
[[0, 7], [1, 12], [2, 7], [3, 3], [4, 0], [5, 4]]

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
//chart
window.onload = function() {

  var dataPoints = [];

  var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    theme: "light2",
    title: {
      text: "Live Data"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "line",
      dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
  });
  updateData();

  // Initial Values
  var xValue = 0;
  var yValue = 10;
  var newDataCount = 6;

  function addData(data) {
    if (newDataCount != 1) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        dataPoints.push({
          x: value[0],
          y: parseInt(value[1])
        });
        xValue++;
        yValue = parseInt(value[1]);
      });
    } else {
      //dataPoints.shift();
      dataPoints.push({
        x: data[0][0],
        y: parseInt(data[0][1])
      });
      xValue++;
      yValue = parseInt(data[0][1]);
    }

    newDataCount = 1;
    chart.render();
    setTimeout(updateData, 1500);
  }
  function updateData() {
    $.getJSON("https://canvasjs.com/services/data/datapoints.php?xstart=" + xValue + "&ystart=" + yValue + "&length=" + newDataCount + "type=json", addData);
  }

}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 370px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the URL for the text file containing the JSON into the updateData function found in your code, replacing "https://www.mywebsite/thetextfile.txt" in the example below with the URL to your text file.

```
function updateData() {
    $.getJSON("https://www.mywebsite/thetextfile.txt", addData);
  }
```

Comment: The txt file is local like :C:\Users\nickv\OneDrive\Bureaublad\Cha how can I use this then

Comment: Move the text file to the same location as your html file and then change the code to the below replacing "thetextfile.txt" with the name of your text file.
function updateData() {
    $.getJSON("thetextfile.txt", addData);
  }